# Why is libclang (libclang.so.3.9) so large(124 MB) in CentOS 6.5 after compiling from source?

Tags: linux, centos6.5, libclang

I have downloaded and compiled libclang following this link on CentOS 6.5: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-llvm-and-clang-on-centos-6

I did just till make as I only need libclang.so and not the clang compiler installed.
libclang.so.3.9 is about 124MB after the compilation!

In Windows libclang.dll is 39MB.

How can I reduce the Linux build to comparable size?

Comment: Did you strip it?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Are there any instructions for that? I need just Clang-c for analyzing a header file.

Comment: Just `strip libclang.so.3.9`. Read `man strip`

Comment: Thanks n.m. Ok that reduced it down to 80MB. Are there any further reductions possible by adjusting the cmake files to not include certain libs but leave the functionality of clang_index() intact?

Comment: This I don't know.